# To avoid not repeating the same verb twice

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Why do I need to write the auxiliary verb "do" down to replace this regular verb in this statement? I mean:

*Love me like you do

Comment: The answer is in your title(to avoid a repetation). *Do* here functions as a pro-verb(not to confuse with proverb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if I'm correct, that line is from a song. Songs tend to follow rhythm, not grammar, so take any sentence constructions found in songs with a grain of salt.

To your actual question: you can consider "like you do" as an adverb in this case. So just as one could say "Love me [better]", we can say "Love me [like you do].

Comment: Yes, it is. This song is sung by the female singer Ellie Goulding.